# Python-docx==0.8.7 package compatibility with 64-bit windows

Tags: python, pip, package, python-docx, win64

I installed this python package using pip that was compatible with Python 2.7. I tried newer versions of the python-docx but those ones did not download properly. Only version 0.8.7 worked as so I installed it using:

```
pip install python-docx==0.8.7
```

But I think it installed a 32 bit version of this package and I am using a 64 bit machine. I know this because while I tried to run my python program using this package I got the error:

```
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This is where the package got downloaded to: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml-3.3.5-py2.7-win32.egg

Anyone have the link to the 64 bit version (win_amd64.whl) of this package? I tried searching in this link([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)) but could not find the package I was looking for.

Comment: This is a problem installing `lxml`, not `python-docx`. `lxml` is the XML library that `python-docx` uses. If you get `lxml` installed and working then your `python-docx` install should proceed smoothly. On Windows machines `lxml` generally must be installed separately.

Comment: @scanny I already have the lxml package. I just did pip install lxml and it said that I already have that package. But after running the script I still get the same DLL load failed error. I edited the error a bit. Since it says from lxml import etree and then ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: The test is having `from lxml import etree` in a Python file by itself and running that and see if you get the error. The `pip install lxml` is inconclusive by itself.

Comment: @scanny Yes I added that import statement and I still got the error:  from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: That confirms that the problem is with getting `lxml` installed, not `python-docx` per se.